# Iframe is not working then pointing Heroku URL

Tags: python, django, heroku, iframe

I have a Python Django app running on https://dj-node-project.herokuapp.com/catalog/, when I put this into an iframe, I'm seeing a blank page. Do I need to enable "iframe" settings on Heroku?

```
<iframe src="https://dj-node-project.herokuapp.com/catalog/">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove middleware as mentioned below
 and you can also use decorator

```
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

  @xframe_options_exempt
  def ok_to_load_in_a_frame(request):
```

Django not allow to use django website as Iframe tag. because django have middleware

'`django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',`

that not allowed to load django site to another website using iframe tag. it check SAMEORIGIN when page loaded. 
you have 
Read full about this topic https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/clickjacking/